# Rellenado de huecos de datos

Tags: python

He creado un código para rellenar los huecos de mis ficheros que no tienen dato por fallo del sistema, para ello he creado un fichero de fechas y este lo estoy comparando con el fichero de datos que tengo. Supuestamente mi código tendría que comparar la primera columna de ambos archivos, y si coincide con el de fechas, pues se guarda la fila completa, si no debería de poner NAN.

El código que he hecho es este:

```
import numpy as np from openpyxl import load_workbook

#Cargamos el fichero excel que queramos procesar 
wb = load_workbook('5_ÁRBOL.xlsx',data_only=True) 
fechas= load_workbook('fechas 2011-2017.xlsx',data_only=True)

print ('Se han cargado los ficheros')

#Elegimos la página del excel que queramos procesar 
sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('arbol5mf1') 
sheet2 = fechas.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja1')

#Creamos varias matrices auxiliares que nos ayudarán en los cálculos 
matriz = np.zeros((736416,5)) 
fecha1 = np.zeros((sheet1.max_row,0)) 
fecha2 = np.zeros((sheet2.max_row,0)) 
copia_excel = np.zeros((sheet1.max_row,sheet1.max_column)) 
copia_fechas = np.zeros((sheet2.max_row,sheet2.max_column))

print ('Se han realizado las matrices auxiliares')

for i in range(3,sheet1.max_row):
    for j in range(1,sheet1.max_column):
        copia_excel[i,j]=sheet1.cell(row=i+1, column=j+1).value
         print ('Se ha rellenado la matriz auxiliar con los datos') for i in range(1,sheet2.max_row):
    for j in range(1,sheet2.max_column):
        copia_fechas[i,j]=sheet2.cell(row=i+1, column=j+1).value
         print ('Se ha rellenado la matriz auxiliar con las fechas')

         for i in range(0,0):
    for j in range(0,sheet1.max_column):
        fecha1[i,j]=sheet1.cell(row=i+1, column=j+1).datetime

print ('Se ha rellenado la matriz auxiliar horas del fichero con los datos')        

for i in range(0,0):
    for j in range(0,sheet2.max_column):
        fecha2[i,j]=sheet2.cell(row=i+1, column=j+1).datetime  

print ('Se ha rellenado la matriz auxiliar horas del fichero fechas')

datos01= fecha1[:,0] 
datos02= copia_excel[:,1] 
datos03= copia_excel[:,2] 
datos04= copia_excel[:,3] 
datos05= copia_excel[:,4] 
datos06= copia_excel[:,5]

fecha01= fecha2[:,0] 
fecha02= copia_fechas[:,1] 
fecha03= copia_fechas[:,2] 
fecha04= copia_fechas[:,3] 
fecha05= copia_fechas[:,4] 
fecha06= copia_fechas[:,5]

c_e = np.array([(datos01,datos02,datos03,datos04,datos05)]) 
c_f = np.array([(fecha01,fecha02,fecha03,fecha04,fecha05)])

print ('Se han creado dos matrices auxiliares')

for i in range(0,sheet2.max_row):
    for j in range (0,0):
        if c_e[i,j]==c_f[i,j]:
            matriz[i,j]=sheet1.cell(row=i+1, column=j+1).value
            print ('Se ha guadado el dato de:',[i,j])

print ('El proceso ha acabado')
```

Se que el código está muy enrevesado, pero no estoy muy puesto en esto de la programación con python y es la única forma que se me ha ocurrido de intentar hacer el código...

Al poner mi código en marcha, me sale el siguiente error:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '#N/A'

¿Alguien me podría ayudar a solucionar este problema o podría decirme que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?
Os dejo el enlace de los ficheros que utilizo de entrada (no son los originales pero si son del estilo que necesito procesar)

5_ÁRBOL.xlsx

```
Measurement Time    Port 1  Port 2  Port 3  Port 4  Port 5
26/05/2011 11:45      NaN   0,145   0,232   0,223   0,236
26/05/2011 11:50      NaN   0,145   0,232   0,223   0,236
26/05/2011 11:55      NaN   0,145   0,232   0,224   0,236
26/05/2011 12:00      NaN   0,145   0,232   0,224   0,236
26/05/2011 12:05      NaN   0,145   0,232   0,224   0,237
26/05/2011 12:10      NaN   0,145   0,232   0,224   0,237
26/05/2011 12:15      NaN   0,145   0,232   0,224   0,237
26/05/2011 12:20      NaN   0,145   0,232   0,224   0,237
26/05/2011 12:25      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,224   0,237
26/05/2011 12:30      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,238
26/05/2011 12:45      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,238
26/05/2011 12:50      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,238
26/05/2011 12:55      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,238
26/05/2011 13:00      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,239
26/05/2011 13:05      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,239
26/05/2011 13:10      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,239
26/05/2011 13:15      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,239
26/05/2011 13:20      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,239
26/05/2011 13:25      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,239
26/05/2011 13:30      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,239
26/05/2011 13:35      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,239
26/05/2011 13:40      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,239
26/05/2011 13:45      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,239
26/05/2011 13:50      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,24
26/05/2011 13:55      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,24
26/05/2011 14:00      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,225   0,24
26/05/2011 14:05      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,226   0,24
26/05/2011 14:10      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,226   0,24
26/05/2011 14:15      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,226   0,24
26/05/2011 14:20      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,226   0,24
26/05/2011 14:25      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,226   0,24
26/05/2011 14:30      NaN   0,145   0,233   0,226   0,24
26/05/2011 14:35      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,24
26/05/2011 14:40      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,24
26/05/2011 14:45      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,24
26/05/2011 14:50      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,24
26/05/2011 14:55      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,24
26/05/2011 15:00      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,24
26/05/2011 15:05      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,24
26/05/2011 15:10      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,24
26/05/2011 15:15      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,24
26/05/2011 15:20      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,241
26/05/2011 15:25      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,241
26/05/2011 15:30      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,241
26/05/2011 15:35      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,241
26/05/2011 15:40      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,241
26/05/2011 15:45      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,241
26/05/2011 15:50      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,241
26/05/2011 15:55      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,241
26/05/2011 16:00      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,241
26/05/2011 16:05      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,241
26/05/2011 16:10      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,241
26/05/2011 16:15      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,241
26/05/2011 16:20      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,226   0,241
26/05/2011 16:25      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,241
26/05/2011 16:30      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,241
26/05/2011 16:35      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,242
26/05/2011 16:40      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,242
26/05/2011 16:45      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,242
26/05/2011 16:50      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,242
26/05/2011 16:55      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,242
26/05/2011 17:00      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,242
26/05/2011 17:05      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,242
26/05/2011 17:10      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,242
26/05/2011 17:15      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,242
26/05/2011 17:20      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,242
26/05/2011 17:25      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,242
26/05/2011 17:30      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,242
26/05/2011 17:35      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 17:40      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 17:45      NaN   0,146   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 17:50      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 17:55      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 18:00      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 18:05      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 18:10      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 18:15      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 18:20      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 18:25      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 18:30      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 18:35      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 18:40      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 18:45      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 18:50      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 18:55      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 19:00      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 19:05      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 19:10      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 19:15      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 19:20      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 19:25      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 19:30      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
```

fechas 2011-2017.xlsx

```
26/05/2011 0:00 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 0:05 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 0:10 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 0:15 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 0:20 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 0:25 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 0:30 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 0:35 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 0:40 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 0:45 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 0:50 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 0:55 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 1:00 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 1:05 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 1:10 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 1:15 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 1:20 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 1:25 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 1:30 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 1:35 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 1:40 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 1:45 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 1:50 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 1:55 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 2:00 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 2:05 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 2:10 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 2:15 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 2:20 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 2:25 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 2:30 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 2:35 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 2:40 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 2:45 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 2:50 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 2:55 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 3:00 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 3:05 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 3:10 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 3:15 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 3:20 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 3:25 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 3:30 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 3:35 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 3:40 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 3:45 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 3:50 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 3:55 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 4:00 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 4:05 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 4:10 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 4:15 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 4:20 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 4:25 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 4:30 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 4:35 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 4:40 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 4:45 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 4:50 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 4:55 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 5:00 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 5:05 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 5:10 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 5:15 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 5:20 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 5:25 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 5:30 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 5:35 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 5:40 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 5:45 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 5:50 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 5:55 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 6:00 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 6:05 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 6:10 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 6:15 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 6:20 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 6:25 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 6:30 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 6:35 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 6:40 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 6:45 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 6:50 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 6:55 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 7:00 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 7:05 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 7:10 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 7:15 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 7:20 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 7:25 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 7:30 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 7:35 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 7:40 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 7:45 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 7:50 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 7:55 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 8:00 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 8:05 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 8:10 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 8:15 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 8:20 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 8:25 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 8:30 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 8:35 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 8:40 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 8:45 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 8:50 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 8:55 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 9:00 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 9:05 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 9:10 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 9:15 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 9:20 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 9:25 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 9:30 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 9:35 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 9:40 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 9:45 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 9:50 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 9:55 5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 10:00    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 10:05    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 10:10    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 10:15    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 10:20    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 10:25    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 10:30    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 10:35    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 10:40    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 10:45    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 10:50    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 10:55    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 11:00    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 11:05    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 11:10    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 11:15    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 11:20    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 11:25    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 11:30    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 11:35    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 11:40    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 11:45    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 11:50    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 11:55    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 12:00    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 12:05    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 12:10    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 12:15    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 12:20    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 12:25    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 12:30    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 12:35    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 12:40    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 12:45    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 12:50    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 12:55    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 13:00    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 13:05    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 13:10    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 13:15    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 13:20    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 13:25    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 13:30    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 13:35    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 13:40    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 13:45    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 13:50    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 13:55    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 14:00    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 14:05    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 14:10    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 14:15    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 14:20    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 14:25    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 14:30    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 14:35    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 14:40    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 14:45    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 14:50    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 14:55    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 15:00    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 15:05    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 15:10    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 15:15    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 15:20    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 15:25    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 15:30    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 15:35    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 15:40    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 15:45    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 15:50    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 15:55    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 16:00    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 16:05    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 16:10    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 16:15    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 16:20    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 16:25    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 16:30    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 16:35    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 16:40    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 16:45    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 16:50    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 16:55    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 17:00    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 17:05    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 17:10    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 17:15    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 17:20    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 17:25    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 17:30    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 17:35    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 17:40    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 17:45    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 17:50    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 17:55    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 18:00    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 18:05    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 18:10    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 18:15    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 18:20    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 18:25    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 18:30    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 18:35    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 18:40    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 18:45    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 18:50    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 18:55    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 19:00    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 19:05    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 19:10    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 19:15    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 19:20    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 19:25    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 19:30    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 19:35    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 19:40    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 19:45    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 19:50    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 19:55    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 20:00    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 20:05    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 20:10    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 20:15    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 20:20    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 20:25    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 20:30    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 20:35    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 20:40    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 20:45    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 20:50    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 20:55    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 21:00    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 21:05    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 21:10    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 21:15    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 21:20    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 21:25    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 21:30    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 21:35    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 21:40    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 21:45    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 21:50    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 21:55    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 22:00    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 22:05    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 22:10    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 22:15    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 22:20    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 22:25    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 22:30    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 22:35    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 22:40    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 22:45    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 22:50    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 22:55    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 23:00    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 23:05    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 23:10    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 23:15    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 23:20    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 23:25    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 23:30    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 23:35    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 23:40    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 23:45    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 23:50    5   146 5   146
26/05/2011 23:55    5   146 5   146
```

Lo que estoy buscando es que cuando coincidan los datos de la primera columna, que me guarde en el fichero de resultado la fila completa del fichero ARBOL, si no que lo ponga todo como NAN para poder rellenar los huecos.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué línea te da el error? Aparentemente alguna celda de tu excel tiene dentro "#N/A", que tu código está intentando tratar como float sin éxito.

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar primero. La linea donde aparece mi error es en la que aparece {copia_excel[i,j]=sheet1.cell(row=i+1, column=j+1).value}

Comment: Posiblemente el acceso a `.value` de una celda dispare el intento de conversión de su contenido a `float`, y si la celda contiene una cadena que no puede ser interpretada como número, te puedes encontrar con el error. Intenta depurar mostrando los valores de `i` `j` a medida que iteras para descubrir las coordenadas de la celda que te da problemas.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias. Voy a determinar en que parte del fichero puede dar problemas. Pero en principio ¿Piensas que el código está correcto y que con él puedo conseguir el rellenado de huecos? es decir, que el problema que me sale es por los datos que tengo, no por el código en si.

Comment: El problema es que `"#N/A"` no se puede interpretar como un float (tipo del array copia_excel). Cuando haces la asignación copia_excel[i,j]="#N/A" se intenta hacer una conversión implícita a float pero falla porque no sabe como interpretar esa cadena ("nan" por ejemplo si es válida) , se puede corregir con un if por ejemplo, pero  creo que [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) te facilitaría mucho la tarea y de forma mucho más eficiente. Seria bueno poder reproducir tu código, un pequeño ejemplo de archivos de entrada y la salida esperada sería de ayuda.

Comment: No he mirado con mucho detalle el código, pues no conozco el módulo `openpyxl`. Yo habría usado `pandas` para resolver este problema. Si la información que manejas no es sensislbe o confidencial, podrías poner un enlace a una excel de ejemplo, que sería útil para poder hacer pruebas y ofrecerte una solución basada en pandas.

Comment: Hola, muchísimas gracias por vuestras respuestas. No he podido contestar antes porque estaba realizando otras tareas, pero me he vuelto a poner con este código y ya no me sale ese error, pero no realiza lo que yo deseo. Voy a editar mi mensaje original para incluir los ficheros que tengo y el resultado que espero tener. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dices tu código es innecesariamente complejo.

Si no entendí mal, creo que de lo que se trata es de completar las fechas/horas que faltan en el archivo Arbol.xlsx. Por ejemplo, se observa que hay muestras cada cinco minutos, pero algunas de ellas faltan, como las que corresponderían a `26/05/2011 12:35` y `26/05/2011 12:40`, entre otras.

Aparentemente los datos del archivo `fechas.xlsx` son irrelevantes, y tan sólo lo usas para obtener la lista de fecha/hora para las que debería haber algo en el otro, y así poder detectar qué fechas faltan.

Todo esto es infinitamente más sencillo usando [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) (siempre que conozcas los entresijos de esta biblioteca, que es lo que lleva más tiempo), pues pandas te permite:

- Leer/escribir excel directamente, con una sola línea (por debajo usa `openpyxl` para ello) dándote como resultado una tabla
- Operar directamente con la tabla "como un todo" sin tener que andar escribiendo bucles
- Parsear las cadenas que representan fechas/horas para convertirlas en objetos `datetime` permitiendo sofisticados cálculos con fechas (cosa que no necesitas ahora, pero puede venirte bien en otro momento)
- Generar rangos de fechas. ¡Este es muy importante! Le puedes dar una fecha/hora de inicio y otra de fin y una frecuencia como 5 minutos y pandas te genera la lista de todos los *timestamp* intermedios
- Usar cualquier columna de la tabla como "index"
- Mezclar tablas en base a sus "index" (rellenando con NaN los que no coincidan)
- Reindexar una tabla en base a otro index (rellenando con NaN los ausentes)
- etc. etc.

De todo lo anterior me voy a quedar con la lectura/escritura de la excel, el parseado de las fechas, la indexación de la tabla en base a la columna de fechas, la generación de rangos de fechas y la reindexación de la tabla según el nuevo rango.

Para poder trabajar con una tabla de ejemplo he copiado y pegado la que tú has suministrado como texto (pandas también puede leer csv, texto plano y otros formatos). Por si alguien quiere reproducir mis pasos, hice lo siguiente:

```
# Copiar a una variable de texto la tabla dada por el usuario
# (no la escribo completa aqui para no ser pesado)
data = """
Measurement Time    Port 1  Port 2  Port 3  Port 4  Port 5
26/05/2011 11:45      NaN   0,145   0,232   0,223   0,236
26/05/2011 11:50      NaN   0,145   0,232   0,223   0,236
...
...
26/05/2011 19:25      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
26/05/2011 19:30      NaN   0,147   0,233   0,227   0,243
"""

# Usar pandas para leerla y tenerla como tabla (dataframe)
import pandas as pd
import io
tabla = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data), sep=r"\s\s+")
```

En el código anterior he puesto como separador de columnas la expresión regular `\s\s+` que significa "dos espacios o más". En tu caso se supone que tienes esta tabla en una hoja excel por lo que la leerías así:

```
tabla = pd.read_excel('5_ÁRBOL.xlsx', sheet_name='arbol5mf1')
# Quizás fueran necesarias otras opciones si la primera fila de la hoja
# no son las cabeceras de las columnas, u otras variaciones
```

En cualquier caso la tabla una vez cargada tendrá esta pinta:

[image: Tabla inicial]

La columna de fechas todavía no es más que una serie de cadenas, sin sentido para pandas. El índice es una mera secuencia de enteros 0, 1, 2, ... después cambiaremos esto.

En cuanto a la segunda hoja de cálculo, realmente no necesitamos leerla. Tan sólo necesitamos saber cuál es la fecha/hora de inicio y la final. En lo que sigue me limitaré a fijar esas variables con un par de fecha/hora de ejemplo. En tu caso podrías si lo prefieres leerlo de la excel, usando también pandas o como hacías antes.

Por ejemplo (elijo empezar a las 11:45 para que se vea mejor el resultado):

```
timestamp_inicio = "26/05/2011 11:45"
timestamp_end = "26/05/2011 23:55"
```

Una vez tenemos la tabla cargada damos los siguientes pasos:

```
# 1, Indicarle a pandas que el índice de la tabla sea la columna Measurement Time
# y después eliminar esa columna (pues ya es el índice)
tabla.index = pd.to_datetime(tabla["Measurement Time"])
tabla = tabla.drop("Measurement Time", axis=1)
```

Ahora el índice son las fechas, que han sido convertidas al tipo datetime:

[image: Indice de tiempos]

Y finalmente el rellenado de las fechas que faltan:

```
# 2. Creo un rango de timestamps espaciados 5 minutos
rango_fechas = pd.date_range(start=timestamp_inicio, end=timestamp_end, freq="5min")
# 3. Reindexo la tabla con este nuevo rango
tabla = tabla.reindex(rango_fechas)
tabla.index.name = "Measurement Time"  # Hay que ponerle nombre que se perdió al reindexar
```

Muestro las 13 primeras filas de la tabla resultante para que se vea cómo ha rellenado con NaN lo que faltaba:

[image: Resultado]

Ya sólo queda guardar como excel el resultado:

```
tabla.to_excel("resultado.xlsx")
```

Cuando abrimos esa excel encontramos que las celdas que eran NaN en pandas salen vacías:

[image: Hoja excel final]

pero si lo prefieres puedes especificar que aparezca la cadena que tú quieras:

```
tabla.to_excel("resultado.xlsx", na_rep="#N/A")
```